# C# 'or' operator?

Tags: c#

Is there an `or` operator in C#?

I want to do:

```
if (ActionsLogWriter.Close or ErrorDumpWriter.Close == true)
{
    // Do stuff here
}
```

But I'm not sure how I could do something like that.

Comment: To be clear, "or" is an operator and not a statement.

Comment: @lndebi: Your questions reveal a strikingly uneven grasp of C#. Consider walking through some tutorials to balance yourself out before tacking package managers and whatever else you're working on. msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/… is a place to start.

Comment: Not to mention you've got a weird if statement to begin with. Why are you only explicit about the 2nd condition being true, and implicit with the first?

Comment: Yeah, i'm kinda self-taught with this stuff and eventually I will take a class, but I like learning as I go more than learning all at once using a book or written text because I can't ask a piece of paper why something isn't working or why it works that way. That is way I'm asking a lot of questions of StackOverflow

Comment: I'm self taught also.  I can use the or operator all day in Python.  Now I'm reading some C# code and seeing this || everywhere and I don't know what to ask.  Thanks to he who asked the question and BIG thanks to those that just give an answer and move on.

Comment: @Justin remember that python uses | for bitwise or, so it's not very different...

Comment: I think it's healthy for stackoverflow to contain answers to questions across the entire spectrum from easy to complex. One stop shops are very powerful. There is a reason why WalMart and Amazon sell everything from bread to vacuum cleaners.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

C# supports two boolean `or` operators: the single bar `|` and the double-bar `||`.

The difference is that `|` always checks both the left and right conditions, while `||` only checks the right-side condition if it's necessary (if the left side evaluates to false).

This is significant when the condition on the right-side involves processing or results in side effects. (For example, if your `ErrorDumpWriter.Close` method took a while to complete or changed something's state.)

Comment: Should that read: || only checks the right-side condition if the left side evaluates to false? Since TRUE OR ANYTHING is always TRUE?

Comment: Just a minor thing - there are ofcourse more boolean operators than that, maybe rephrase to "two boolean/logic OR operators".

Comment: Be careful:  || is a logical operator and | is a binary operator

Comment: @Matthieu: No, if the operands are boolean, the |-operator is a logical operator. It's only treated as binary if operands are integral.

Comment: There is also the `or` keyword now too...

Answer (score 19):

As of C# 9, there is an `or` keyword that can be used in matching a "disjunctive pattern". This is part of several new [pattern matching enhancements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-9#pattern-matching-enhancements) in this version.

An example from the docs:

```
public static bool IsLetter(this char c) => c is >= 'a' and <= 'z' or >= 'A' and <= 'Z';
```

Answer (score 9):

Also worth mentioning, in C# the OR operator is short-circuiting. In your example, Close seems to be a property, but if it were a method, it's worth noting that:

```
if (ActionsLogWriter.Close() || ErrorDumpWriter.Close())
```

is fundamentally different from

```
if (ErrorDumpWriter.Close() || ActionsLogWriter.Close())
```

In C#, if the first expression returns true, the second expression will not be evaluated at all. Just be aware of this. It actually works to your advantage most of the time.

Comment: Does it matter if it's a property or method? In this context I would guess the property-code is called just as well as for methods.

Comment: That is a good point. If the properties had side effects (which is also very bad design) the same caveat applies.

Answer (score 4):

```
if (ActionsLogWriter.Close || ErrorDumpWriter.Close == true)
{    // Do stuff here
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The single " | " operator will evaluate both sides of the expression.

```
    if (ActionsLogWriter.Close | ErrorDumpWriter.Close == true)
{
    // Do stuff here
}
```

The double operator " || " will only evaluate the left side if the expression returns true.

```
    if (ActionsLogWriter.Close || ErrorDumpWriter.Close == true)
{
    // Do stuff here
}
```

C# has many similarities to C++ but their still are differences between the two languages ;)

Answer (score 2):

just like in C and C++, the boolean or operator is `||`

```
if (ActionsLogWriter.Close || ErrorDumpWriter.Close == true)
{
    // Do stuff here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Or is `||` in C#.

You may have a look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d(VS.71).aspx).