# If - Or statement evaluates to TRUE when in fact it should be FALSE

Tags: c#, if-statement

Not sure what I am missing here.. Should be pretty simple..

tblCurrent does NOT equal NULL
tblCurrent.Rows.Count DOES equal 0

```
if (tblCurrent != null | tblCurrent.Rows.Count != 0)
{
    //Do something
}
else
{
    // This is what I want
}
```

It should see that the right condition is 0 so it should return false and put in the else block?  What am I missing??

Comment: If `tblCurrent` is not null then `tblCurrent != null` is true and it would not go to the else block.

Comment: If `tblCurrent != null`, that condition will always evaluate to `true`. Are you sure you don't want to use AND (`&&`)? Also, you should be using `||` instead of `|`.

Comment: Think about it -- you're asking it to check if `tblCurrent` is not null, and since `tblCurrent` is not null, guess how it evaluates?

Comment: Please investigate a little bit before posting questions. You are using the wrong operator.

Comment: Yes but I also have the tblCurrent.Rows.Count != 0 condition.  If either one of these conditions evaluate to false I want to be in the else block.  And the rows.count does evaluate to false.  I thought that a single pipe | checked both conditions

Comment: @Ron, a [bitwise or (|)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kxszd0kx.aspx) is way different than a [conditional or (||)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6373h346.aspx).

Comment: What's with all these votes to close? Although this is definitely not a hard question, but it's not a "check the manual" or "gimmecodez" question either! I don't think it should be closed for "no effort".

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables Even the straight boolean logic could be hard to someone with no prior exposure to it. My personal criterion of sufficient "minimal understanding" is posting relevant code that compiles, which OP did :-)

Comment: To clarify I got that information from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1746302/c-sharp-or-operator which was the top rated answer so I figured that was my problem.  I should looked further in the comments section -  Thank you dasblinkenlight for the clarification.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If  `tblCurrent` does not equal `null`, then `tblCurrent != null` evaluates to `true`, so the overall `OR` would evaluate to `true` as well, because an `OR` evaluates to `true` if, and only if, one or both of its sides evaluate to `true`.

It looks like your logic should have used the `AND` operator `&&` instead of an `OR`, like this:

```
if (tblCurrent != null && tblCurrent.Rows.Count != 0) {
    ...
} else {
    ...
}
```

The `&&` operator *short-circuits* the evaluation, so you would not get an exception even when the `tblCurrent` is `null`.

Comment: The && operator short-circuits the evaluation, so you would not get an exception even when the tblCurrent is null.

I think this may be where I was getting lost because there will be times that the table is actually null and I dont want to also be checking the rows equal 0 on a null table

Comment: @Ron The `&&` operator checks the left side first, and sees if it can decide the overall result based on the left side alone. Since `AND` evaluates to `false` when either side is false, the `&&` knows the answer to `false && anythingElse` without knowing what that `anythingElse` might be. In your case, when `tblCurrent` is `null`, `tblCurrent != null` would evaluate to `false`, so `&&` would not go any further, and return `false`. The `tblCurrent.Rows` expression would not get evaluated. The official name of that trick is short-circuiting.

Answer (score 3):

The correct [`OR operator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6373h346.aspx) is `||`.
The [`| operator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kxszd0kx.aspx) is a `bitwise OR`.

Your logic requires `AND`, not `OR`.

```
if (tblCurrent != null && tblCurrent.Rows.Count != 0)
```

Comment: It's not actually the bitwise OR in context, because both operands are boolean.  It's just a non-short circuiting OR.  If the operands were numeric then it would be a bitwise OR.