# How do I filter a list containing another list in C#?

Tags: c#, linq, filtering

I have two classes connected via a one-to-many relationship:

```
public class Movie
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Synopsis { get; set; }
    public IList<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
}

public class Tag
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

How do I find all movies containing a given string? I manage as long as I do not dive into the tags:

```
var result = movies.Where(m => m.Title.Contains(searchString) |
                               m.Synopsis.Contains(searchString));
```

Here is some pseudo code, only working in my dreams:

```
var result = movies.Where(m => m.Title.Contains(searchString) |
                               m.Synopsis.Contains(searchString) | 
                               m.Tags.Name.Contains(searchString)); 
                              // Cannot access Name property of Tags like this
```

What is the right way to do it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You cannot access the properties of a `Tag` because you do not hold a reference to `Tag` but to a collection of tags. Therefore you need to use linq's [`.Any`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972(v=vs.110).aspx) to query:

> Determines whether any element of a sequence satisfies a condition.

So:

```
var result = movies.Where(m => m.Title.Contains(searchString) |
                               m.Synopsis.Contains(searchString) | 
                               m.Tags.Any(t => t.Name.Contains(searchString)));
```

---

*Also consider using [`||` operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6373h346(v=vs.71).aspx) instead of [`|` operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kxszd0kx(v=vs.71).aspx). Both perform a logical `OR` but the former will do it lazily (i.e. stop as soon as it runs into a `true`). Read more: [C# 'or' operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1746302/6400526) and*