# How to 'Properly use if else on variables with different values'

Tags: c#, variables, if-statement

I have an if-else statement wherein it would not run if two variables have the same value. But if those two variables are both "0", it would run.

```
if (a != b){
     //it should also proceed here if a and b are both "0". What should my statement be?
}
```

Comment: What's your variable type?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# 'or' operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1746302/c-sharp-or-operator)

Comment: it is actually a string

Comment: Have you check the string Length?

Answer (score 2):

```
I've solved it guys. Thank you.

if (a != b || (a == "0" && b == "0")){
   //it should also proceed here if a and b are both "0". What should my statement be?
}
```